# Spark Memory Error Java Runtime Environment

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark job made in python, where I retrieve data from Redshift, and then I apply many transformations, join, filter, withColumn, agg ...
There are around 30K records in the dataframes
I perform all the transformation and when I try to write an AVRO file the spark job fails

My spark submit:

```
. /usr/bin/spark-submit --packages="com.databricks:spark-avro_2.11:3.2.0" --jars RedshiftJDBC42-1.2.1.1001.jar --deploy-mode client --master yarn --num-executors 10 --executor-cores 3 --executor-memory 10G --driver-memory 14g --conf spark.sql.broadcastTimeout=3600 --conf spark.network.timeout=10000000 --py-files dependencies.zip iface_extractions.py 2016-10-01 > output.log
```

I'm using --executor-memory 10G --driver-memory 14g, 6 machines in amazon with 8 cores and 15G RAM, why Im getting out of memory error ???

Error returned:

```
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 196608 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/hadoop/hs_err_pid13688.log
```

This is the end of spark log:

```
17/05/29 10:13:09 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 21.0 (TID 19, ip-10-185-53-172.eu-west-1.compute.internal, executor 2, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, 5779 bytes)
17/05/29 10:13:09 INFO TransportClientFactory: Successfully created connection to ip-10-185-53-172.eu-west-1.compute.internal/10.185.53.172:39759 after 3 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
17/05/29 10:13:09 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_24_piece0 in memory on ip-10-185-53-172.eu-west-1.compute.internal:39759 (size: 8.9 KB, free: 5.3 GB)
17/05/29 10:13:11 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_8_piece0 on 10.185.52.91:43829 in memory (size: 30.4 KB, free: 8.2 GB)
17/05/29 10:13:11 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_8_piece0 on ip-10-185-52-186.eu-west-1.compute.internal:35010 in memory (size: 30.4 KB, free: 5.8 GB)
17/05/29 10:13:11 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_7_piece0 on 10.185.52.91:43829 in memory (size: 30.3 KB, free: 8.2 GB)
17/05/29 10:13:11 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_7_piece0 on ip-10-185-52-186.eu-west-1.compute.internal:35010 in memory (size: 30.3 KB, free: 5.8 GB)
17/05/29 10:13:11 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_6_piece0 on 10.185.52.91:43829 in memory (size: 30.6 KB, free: 8.2 GB)
17/05/29 10:13:11 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_6_piece0 on ip-10-185-52-186.eu-west-1.compute.internal:35010 in memory (size: 30.6 KB, free: 5.8 GB)
17/05/29 10:13:11 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added taskresult_2 in memory on ip-10-185-53-172.eu-west-1.compute.internal:39759 (size: 499.6 MB, free: 4.8 GB)
17/05/29 10:13:11 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 23.0 (TID 20, ip-10-185-53-172.eu-west-1.compute.internal, executor 2, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, 5779 bytes)
17/05/29 10:13:12 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_25_piece0 in memory on ip-10-185-53-172.eu-west-1.compute.internal:39759 (size: 8.8 KB, free: 4.8 GB)
17/05/29 10:13:13 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 3) in 270161 ms on ip-10-185-53-172.eu-west-1.compute.internal (executor 2) (1/1)
17/05/29 10:13:13 INFO YarnScheduler: Removed TaskSet 3.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
17/05/29 10:13:13 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 3 (run at ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) finished in 270.162 s
17/05/29 10:13:13 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 3 finished: run at ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142, took 270.230067 s
17/05/29 10:13:13 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed taskresult_3 on ip-10-185-53-172.eu-west-1.compute.internal:39759 in memory (size: 499.5 MB, free: 5.3 GB)
17/05/29 10:13:16 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_3_piece0 on 10.185.52.91:43829 in memory (size: 5.5 KB, free: 8.2 GB)
17/05/29 10:13:17 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_3_piece0 on ip-10-185-53-172.eu-west-1.compute.internal:39759 in memory (size: 5.5 KB, free: 5.3 GB)
17/05/29 10:13:20 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 2) in 276982 ms on ip-10-185-53-172.eu-west-1.compute.internal (executor 2) (1/1)
17/05/29 10:13:20 INFO YarnScheduler: Removed TaskSet 2.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
17/05/29 10:13:20 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 2 (run at ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) finished in 276.984 s
17/05/29 10:13:20 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 2 finished: run at ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142, took 277.000009 s
17/05/29 10:13:20 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed taskresult_2 on ip-10-185-53-172.eu-west-1.compute.internal:39759 in memory (size: 499.6 MB, free: 5.8 GB)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x0000000667766000, 196608, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
```

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the execution plan from web UI's Details for Query (in SQL tab)?

Comment: I think the problem comes from there, my explain plan is close to 1k lines... ¿could be the reason?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot to see the plan?

Comment: Here the plan: https://file.town/uploaded/tuypb77jme58e56ws8su759ao

This is the plan to calculate one field, there are three more fields that the calculations are similar

Comment: Edit your question and attach the screenshot.

Comment: are 1k lines, cant attach